# Multiple small queries, or one big query while storing xml data into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm parsing an xml file which I loop through and store information into a SQL Server. I send a `MERGE` query to either insert or update information.

Is it best to store this information in a variable, and send query after the loop has finished, or send numerous small queries within the loop? I expect 60-100 queries for each loop.

```
$DOM=simplexml_load_file($url);
$info=$DOM->info;
foreach($info as $i){
  $i_name=$i['name'];
  $i_id=$i['id'];
  ...
  $q=sqlsrv_query($conn,"
    MERGE dbo.members m USING (
      SELECT 
        '$i_name' as name,
        '$i_id' as id,
         ...
    ) s ON ( m.id=s.id ) 
      WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET ...
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ...
  ");
}
```

Comment: tiny example would be nice

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the best performance comes from batching the SQL statements several hundred at a time.

Hopefully the language your own (php? perl? can't tell) has a utility for this, otherwise you can easily code it up yourself.

Of course, if your DB is on the same machine it probably makes no difference.

Comment: I'm using php w/ sqlsrv ext. The problem is that the xml files are huge. I'm talking 50-60k queries in total. I parse every hour, on a scheduled service. it takes a few minutes between fetching xml, and parsing, mostly fetching. Each xml file contains 60-70 queries that must be executed. So, the idea was should I send these 60-70 queries together or one at a time.

Comment: Yes, batching them will give you some improvement. Presumably PHP has some string builder utility.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various factors. You could setup a test scenario and check the performance of both options, then choose whatever is better for your case. We had a similar case and best option was to have a stored procedure that received a table with all the needed values.

Check this other similar questions, they are not exactly same as yours but I believe the answers given there will help you a lot.

[Update or Merge very big tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6001980/1297603)

[Multiple INSERT statements vs. single INSERT with multiple VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8635818/1297603)